# HATBM relation error

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with HABTM relation in cakephp. I have 2 models Campaign and Person I've created 3 database tables campaings, persons and campaigns_persons.
The models looks like this:

**Campaign**

```
class Campaign extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Campaign';
    var $displayField = 'nombre';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id'
        ),
        'Template' => array(
            'className' => 'Template',
            'foreignKey' => 'template_id'
        )
    );
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Persona' =>
        array('className' => 'Person',
            'joinTable' => 'campaigns_persons',
            'foreignKey' => 'campaign_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'person_id',
            'with' => '',
            'conditions' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'unique' => true,
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

**Person**

```
class Person extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Person';
    var $displayField = 'name';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        ),
    );
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
        $this->Campaign->create();
    if ($this->Campaign->save($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->write('campaign_id', $this->Campaign->id);
        $this->Session->setFlash(__("Listado de clientes agregado", true));
        return true;
    }//fin saveAll
```

It throws me this error:

```
    Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
    1   0.0012  372600  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
    2   0.1148  4012344 Dispatcher->dispatch( ) ..\index.php:86
    3   0.1319  4967600 Dispatcher->_invoke( )  ..\dispatcher.php:171
    4   2.2085  9815800 call_user_func_array ( )    ..\dispatcher.php:204
    5   2.2085  9815968 CampaignsController->end_campaign( )    ..\dispatcher.php:204
    6   2.4742  9845328 CampaignsController->__saveAll( )   ..\campaigns_controller.php:221
    7   2.4743  9845568 Model->save( )  ..\campaigns_controller.php:281
```

I don't know what happened.

Comment: Which version of cakephp?

Comment: Based on your error message there's more going on in your controller than the code you posted. `end_campaign()`, then `__saveAll()` (which starts at line 221, while the `Model::save()` is at line 281 what's going on in those 60 lines of code?)